# Visual Source Safe vs. GIT for Large C# .Net Development Project

Tags: .net, git, svn, version-control, visual-sourcesafe

I am currently working with a development company in India on a large C# .Net cloud-based application.

We have millions of lines of code and 10+ developers working on the project.

They are currently using [Microsoft Visual SourceSafe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_SourceSafe) for our version control.

I have spoken to many people and they have all said that using VSS is a bad idea and is very outdated.

The general consensus was that GIT or Subversion would be a better choice.

Before I have them move in one direction or the other, I wanted to get some feedback from the experts in the StackOverflow community since I'm sure people have more experience in this than I do.

If we do go with GIT, is it going to be complicated for them to learn? I definitely don't want to lose a lot of time making the switch since we have other important goals.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's lots of resources for this already; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426662/git-svn-for-asp-net-development-instead-of-vss?rq=1 for example. As an aside, I recently worked on a project that had a fairly large VSS database. Once they get fairly big, corruption of the database becomes a real risk, apparently, and this did indeed happen several times. Moved to SVN and didn't look back (support for features like branching and integration with other products). Your mileage may vary!

Comment: This is most likely a Not Constructive question. I don't think anyone will step up in favor of VSS but the Subversion vs Git is a subjetive argument. For what it's worth my recommendation would be to go with SVN.

Comment: If you're already a Microsoft shop, look into Team Foundation Server. You should be able to (mostly) painlessly migrate VSS to TFS.

Answer (score 3):

Well, **almost any other** SCM after VSS will be better choice. I think, you have not limit your search-area to these two (SVN|Git) SCM, but, in an unhurried manner and taking into account all local-specific requirements, make your choice. I can add to list

- Plastic SCM
- Mercurial

and note that all the options have their advantages and disadvantages. Answer on your question

> If we do go with GIT, is it going to be complicated for them to learn?

is obvious: **YES, it will be!!!** It will be most complicated way compared to any other migration, and in process of using later also